# Wrong rendering in narrow width in Safari

Tags: bug, status-declined, mathjax

When I view the front page right now in Safari, I see:
[image: question mark appears mid-equation]
Notice that the question mark, which the poster properly placed at the end of the equation (see the question (before another edit removed the question mark) at https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/329925/2), appears at the end of the first line, mid-inequality.  I think that this is probably a result of a relatively narrow window width (138 characters).  I'm not sure what to say about this except that it's obviously (presumably?) not the way it should be rendering.

Comment: Looks OK to me, and I'm also using Safari. But I think the title was better before OP posted it, in the version without all the math.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, did you try it with a narrow window?

Comment: No. (Why would I?)

Comment: To me this looks a bit similar to this bug report: [MathJax rendering issue while looking at someone's profile](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29728). (Although that one is already marked status completed.)

Comment: @GerryMyerson, because that's the circumstance under which I'm seeing it.  (I put this in the title, but not the body, so I guess I should edit.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, I agree that [that](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4198/wrong-rendering-in-narrow-width-in-safari#comment19933_4198) looks like a similar error (although it's hard to tell if two rendering issues are caused by the same underlying bug, and this one seems like it might be related to window width—although I neglected to try re-sizing the window to see, and now the title's changed), but, as you say, it's happening for me right now, despite the `{status-completed}` tag.

Comment: I'm reminded of an old joke. Man goes to the doctor, says "Doc, it hurts when I raise my arm like this [raises his arm to show doctor what he means]." Doctor replies, "So, don't raise your arm like that!"

Comment: @SpencerG, I notice the tag [tag:status-review] was [removed](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/revisions/4198/6), but no new tag was added.  Does that mean that, on review, this was determined not to be a bug; or that it was determined to be a bug, but won't be fixed; or something else?

Comment: @LSpice Sorry for the confusion it was my error. We were doing an internal review of these older bug reports, and I pulled the tag off by accident. I have not put a new status on it, as it will create a new ticket via our automation. So still monitoring it; I just messed up our internal process. That being said, I could not duplicate this on Safari when I tried to.

Comment: @SpencerG, [re](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4198/wrong-rendering-in-narrow-width-in-safari#comment27981_4198), no worries.  It seems only to happen on the front page (or other summary page, i.e., not on individual question pages) with titles with long math formulæ with narrow windows.  I don't see any on the front page right now, but would be happy to comment here next time I see one, if that would help.

Comment: Due to the very minimal impact of this bug, we won't be correcting it.

Comment: @SpencerG, is this bug the same as [that one](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5575), so that I should close as duplicate?

Comment: @LSpice I think that is different. I will put a status review tag on it so that we can look into it a bit more.