# Math-mode formula in comment breaks incorrectly across lines

Tags: bug, mathjax, comments

In the following [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393934/are-there-always-more-conjugacy-classes-in-the-kernel-of-a-morphism-to-z-2-tha/393938#comment1005734_393938), both summands should appear before the period:
[image: A period appears in the middle of a formula]
The source for the comment is:

> `$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}$Proof of the well known fact: $\Hom_H(V_H, V_H) = \Hom_G(V_H^G, V) = \Hom_G(V \oplus (V \otimes \epsilon), V) = 1 + [V \otimes \epsilon \cong V]$.`

I've [asked a related question before](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4198/wrong-rendering-in-narrow-width-in-safari), but, in that case, it was able to be resolved by displaying the window full-size.  That does not work in this case.  (In fact, re-sizing the window doesn't seem to change anything; I always see the period immediately after the $1$.)

EDIT:  The display above is what it looks like in desktop macOS Firefox.  Desktop Safari gives me a different, but still wrong, line break:
[image: Differently bad line break on Safari]
It sure seems like the problems of [overflowing math](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1148/the-math-its-overflowing) were fixed by giving each formula the maximum width that wouldn't overflow, and rendering it as a multi-line formula within that width if necessary—which is good!—but then the surrounding text needs also to be aware of this.

Comment: I see that comment correctly, with the formula in one line and the dot at the end (and the line break before the formula). Which browser do you use?

Comment: @StefanKohl, the first screenshot was from Firefox.  I have now edited in what I see in Safari.  Probably the conditions that trigger this bad breaking will be different depending on the particularities of the setups of different users, but I guess every user will probably see some variant of this some time.  (It seems to be triggered when we would previously have seen [overflowing math](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1148/the-math-its-overflowing).)

Comment: Is the way the comment is displayed different if you [change the Math Renderer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30859#30860)? This is what I see in Chrome with HTML-CSS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMla8.png