# How is TeX rendered in edit summaries?

Tags: discussion, status-review, mathjax, editing

I recently [edited](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/438406/3) a question [Dynkin type classification for 2-dimensional hypersurfaces in non-commutative space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438406/dynkin-type-classification-for-2-dimensional-hypersurfaces-in-non-commutative-sp), and entered as my edit summary "$<x,y>$ -> $\langle x,y\rangle$" `$<x,y>$ -> $\langle x,y\rangle$`.  To my surprise, rather than displaying as it does here, this summary displays in the [list of revisions](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/438406/revisions) as:

[image: Unexpected line breaks]

Why is each $y$ and each closing delimiter set on a separate line?

Comment: This might be another instance of improper MathJax wrapping, like observed in [MathJax formula has extraneous line breaks on the user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378009) on Meta SE. Also, in the [direct link](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/438406/3) to your revision, the edit summary is rendered correctly for me.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist, [thanks](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5575/how-is-tex-rendered-in-edit-summaries#comment28251_5575)!  You're right; this question is probably a near-duplicate of [that one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378009).  However, since we can't close as cross-site duplicates—is there a similar question already here on MO?  (I also see the edit summary rendered correctly in the direct link to the revision itself; the problem I describe only occurs for me on the list of revisions.)

Comment: The closest duplicate on this site would be Matt F.'s [answer to "What is the deal with changes to the front page?"](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5246), in particular the part added after "Update". I've also left a [comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5230/what-is-the-deal-with-changes-to-the-front-page/5246#comment27639_5246) there with links to similar bug reports. However, I would recommend leaving this question open.

Comment: I knew this looked familiar. I now think that it may actually be a duplicate of a prior post by ... [me](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4198). But I'll wait to see if it's the same bug.

Comment: I don't believe it is the same bug, because this bug doesn't occur only on narrow width screens, as witnessed by your screenshot. (It seems the question on main has been deleted in the meantime.)